# Scanning DataMatrix QR code on Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, qr-code, barcode-scanner, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to scan a QR code and get the data from it on my raspberry pi.

The scanner I am using is the: [DS6510b-2d](https://www.google.com/search?q=ds6510b-2d&client=avast-a-2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPh-PIlof5AhXoN-wKHRe-DR4Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1920&bih=929&dpr=1#imgrc=k5ht247eCod7GM)
I am scanning the QR code on the picture below the post:

This QR code has separators so I can differentiate the DATA.

When I scan the QR code on Windows I get the following result:

**10ABC123↔21U001273↔12040104↔3712345678**
This is correct and exactly what I need.

When I scan the QR code connected to the raspberry I get the following:

**10ABC12321U001273120401043712345678** Here it is missing the sepperators, this makes it impossible to differentiate the data.

How do I get it so when I scan the QR code on my raspberry it also shows the sepperators?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**QR CODE:**

[image]

Comment: Why not find out the difference between a program running on Windows and a program running on a Raspberry Pi? Or try adding that information and source code to your question. Without such information, it would be difficult to get advice and answers.

Comment: @kunif The QR code scanner is connected to the pc using USB. The Windows pc or raspberry pi see it as a keyboard. When I scan a barcode I have my mouse highlighted in a text file and it will put the output there. In windows it does it correctly but on the raspberry it does not. Does it maybe have to do with how the raspberry is reading the input from the USB port?

Comment: First of all, there will be differences in the functions of the OS and device drivers. And there may be a difference in the program that reads the keyboard input notification and stores it in a text file. For example, there is a difference in interpretation when inputting a control key other than normal displayable characters or when inputting a character code using the Alt key. Instead of storing the text, why not run a program that records and stores the details of KeyDown/KeyUp notifications to see the difference?

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas, though I can test none as I don't have your scanner...

---

You could try starting a *"virtual console"*, see [here](https://makeuseof.com/what-are-linux-virtual-consoles), which is text-based and doesn't use X11, and then scanning with your scanner to see if the X11 server and keyboard mappings are *"eating"* your separators.

I'm not proposing this as a permanent solution, just a step in working out the issue.

---

Or, with X11 server started, you could run `xev` to see what X events are generated when you scan and potentially then use `xmodmap` to convert you *"left right double arrow"* thing into some other symbol all concerned parties can work with.

---

I don't use Windows but there must be a tool to get the Unicode codepoint of your *"left right double arrow"* thing. I guess it is `U+21d4`, see [here](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+21D4).

Then you could type/generate that codepoint on the Raspberry Pi using [this](https://odoepner.wordpress.com/2018/01/04/enter-unicode-characters-in-linux/) and see what Raspbian makes of it.